# Calculation method not reading input

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having an issue where the calculation method keeps on returning the default value of result and the method doesn't seem to read the input of the operator in the form.

Does anyone know what I have done wrong?

This is my code:

```
namespace Prac5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                decimal Operand1 = Convert.ToDecimal(txtOperand1.Text);
                decimal Operand2 = Convert.ToDecimal(txtOperand2.Text);
                string Operator = Convert.ToString(txtOperator);

                if ((Operand1 <= 1000000 && Operand1 >= 1) && (Operand2 <= 1000000 && Operand2 >= 1))
                {                   
                    decimal Result = Calculation(Operand1, Operand2, Operator);
                    Result = Math.Round(Result, 4);
                    txtResult.Text = Result.ToString();                  
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n\n" +
                ex.GetType().ToString() + "\n" +
                ex.StackTrace, "Exception");
            }         
        }

        private decimal Calculation(decimal Operand1, decimal Operand2, string Operator)
        {           
            decimal Result = 0;
            switch (Operator = Convert.ToString(txtOperator))
            {
                case "+":
                    return Result = Operand1 + Operand2;
                case "-":
                    return Result = Operand1 - Operand2;
                case "*":
                    return Result = Operand1 * Operand2;
                case "/":
                    return Result = Operand1 / Operand2;
                default:
                    return Result;
            }
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Either return after switch or do this:`Result = Operand1 - Operand2; return Result`; do the same for all cases.

Comment: `switch (Operator = Convert.ToString(txtOperator))` doesn't make a lot of sense. Converting a string to a string is kind of pointless

Comment: Also try using verbs for method names so `Calculate` would be more readable and as per convention.

Comment: @camiloterevinto This is not a duplicate of that thread. Totally different issue.

Comment: Also just do `switch(operator)`

Comment: @camiloterevinto Agree but If the OP fixed that part, do you think it would solve the issue?

Comment: @camiloterevinto Apologies, I just noticed `Convert.ToString(txtOperator);`, I thought it was `Convert.ToString(txtOperator.Text);`. My bad.

Comment: @CodingYoshi No worries, happens to us all. Cleaning up...

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys will take everything into account, question answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the operator out of the text box you are trying to convert the text box to a string instead of the text.

```
string Operator = Convert.ToString(txtOperator);
```

should be

```
string Operator = txtOperator.Text;
```